# How to insert multiple value checkbox?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert the values of my check box into the database using this code, its working but in the back end didn't checked.

My HTML

```
<div class="form-group relocate">
    <label for="contact_method"><?php _e('Best Contact Method', 'jobboard') ?></label>
    <?php $contact_method = get_post_meta($resume_id, 'resume_contact_method', true); ?>
    <ul>
        <li class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="resume_contact_method" name="resume_contact_method[]" value="email" <?php if($contact_method){echo (in_array('email', $contact_method)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; }?>><label for="resume_contact_method_email"><?php _e( 'Email', 'jobboard' ); ?></label>
        </li>
        <li class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="resume_contact_method" name="resume_contact_method[]" value="phone" <?php if($contact_method){echo (in_array('phone', $contact_method)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; }?>><label for="resume_contact_method_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'jobboard' ); ?></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

My PHP function

```
$resume_contact_methods = array();
$i = 0;
foreach( $data['resume_contact_method'] as $resume_contact_method ) {
    if($resume_contact_method != '') {
        $resume_contact_methods[] = $data['resume_contact_method'][$i];
    }
    $i++;
}

$meta_input = array(
    'resume_contact_method' => $resume_contact_methods,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

in your HTML you can have your checkboxes like this (considering you are storing ids of some sort)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value"1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value"24" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value"56" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value"100" />
```

On you php side you can use function implode to form ids into a string as shown below (considering you are doing a POST)

```
$ids = implode(",",$_POST["ids"]);
```

Where you read from the database you can transform the value from db to an array like this

```
$ids_array = explode(",",$row->ids); // this $row->ids will depend on how you fetch the data from database
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Kumar. P I'm trying to insert the values of my check box into the database using this code, its working but the only data that is entering the data base is the value of the last checkbox that I clicked

Comment: @Naresh Kumar .P, how to add counter with each value, like 1- value, 2-value and 3-value ...